# What is a sutiable database solution that would save key, value and queired with thousands of keys to return thousands of values?

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I want to save key: value into some database. That would be rare operation to write.
Reading on the other hand.
I want to send multiple keys (thousands) and retrieve values for those keys with speed.

Answer (score 0):

[ElastiCache for Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/) or [ElastiCache for Memcached](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/memcached/) would be the managed AWS solution.

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis-vs-memcached/) should help you decide which to pick.